Importing bevy assets inside pseudo "microfrontend"(Nextjs multizones)
I have a bevy app, that I want to rewrite to Nextjs multizones.
Here's my next.config.js:
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/wasm-shuttle',
        destination: https://bevy-game.shuttleapp.rs`/,
              },
              {
                  source: '/wasm-shuttle/:path',
                 destination: `https://bevy-game.shuttleapp.rs/:path,
              }
           ]
      },
  headers: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: "/wasm-shuttle",
        headers: getCorsHeaders(),
      },
      {
        source: "/wasm-shuttle/:path*",
        headers: getCorsHeaders(),
      },
    ];
  },

It basically makes, my app show on a wasm-shuttle endpoint.
Here's my GitHub project(It's a default shuttle bevy project with little attempts to make things work).
The problem in this project is loading assets because when I run it inside my Next application, it looks inside my Nextjs project assets, and not the actual bevy project.

And here, is how the assets are loaded:
fn main_menu(mut commands: Commands, asset_server: Res<AssetServer>) {
    let font = asset_server.load("Roboto-Black.ttf"); ...

